# In practical, what really is a memory word in PLC?

Tags: memory, programmable-logic, plc

I came across some plc code (structured text) being used in an industrial company. When I asked the question, I got a blurry answer. However,  what I picked up is that it has something to do with the SCADA and PLC interacting. Although I'm really not sure what exactly a memory word is.

Any information on this will really be appreciated.

Comment: Just a word in memory. A grouping of bits.What is your computing background?

Comment: `word` may be referring to two or more bytes

Comment: What did you try to find out? Which resources did you look up? BTW, in general `word` might be any bit size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Most PLCs use 16-bit words.
- A word can be used to represent

  - a 16-bit unsigned integer (0 to 65,535).
  - a 16-bit signed integer (-32,768 to 32,767).
  - 16 individual bits (such as a group of boolean values).

> ... what I picked up is that it has something to do with the SCADA and PLC interacting.

Nope. The PLC uses words for variable storage. A SCADA (Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition System) can be made to read or write to a variable for monitoring or control purposes but the PLC word exists whether there is SCADA or not.

*Table 1. [IEC 61131-3 data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3).*

- Bit Strings – groups of on/off values

  - BYTE – 8 bit (1 byte)
  - WORD – 16 bit (2 byte)
  - DWORD – 32 bit (4 byte)
  - LWORD – 64 bit (8 byte)
- INTEGER – whole numbers (Considering byte size 8 bits)

  - SINT – signed short integer (1 byte)
  - INT – signed integer (2 byte)
  - DINT – signed double integer (4 byte)
  - LINT – signed long integer (8 byte)
  - USINT – Unsigned short integer (1 byte)
  - UINT – Unsigned integer (2 byte)
  - UDINT – Unsigned double integer (4 byte)
  - ULINT – Unsigned long integer (8 byte)
- REAL – floating point IEC 60559 (same as IEEE 754-2008)

  - REAL – (4 byte)
  - LREAL – (8 byte)
- Duration

  - TIME – (4 byte). Literals in the form of T#5m90s15ms
  - LTIME – (8 byte). Literals extend to nanoseconds in the form of T#5m90s15ms542us15ns
- Date

  - DATE – calendar date (Size is not specified)
  - LDATE – calendar date (Size is not specified)
- Time of day

  - TIME_OF_DAY / TOD – clock time(Size is not specified)
  - LTIME_OF_DAY / LTOD – clock time (8 byte)
- Date and time of Day

  - DATE_AND_TIME / DT – time and date(Size is not specified)
  - LDATE_AND_TIME / LDT – time and date(8 byte)
- Character / Character string

  - CHAR – Single-byte character (1 byte)
  - WCHAR – Double-byte character (2 byte)
  - STRING – Variable-length single-byte character string. Literals specified with single quote, 'This is a STRING Literal'
  - WSTRING – Variable-length double-byte character string. Literals specified with a double quote, "This is a WSTRING Literal"